# How to enable logrotation for traefik?

Tags: traefik

How do I enable log rotation for log files e.g. access.log.

Is this built in ?

Docs only say "This allows the logs to be rotated and processed by an external program, such as logrotate"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Log Rotation**
>
> Traefik will close and reopen its log files, assuming they're configured, on receipt of a `USR1` signal. This allows the logs to be rotated and processed by an external program, such as `logrotate`.

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/logs/#log-rotation

Comment: Hi, I used this approach on a single docker host, using "docker-compose restart" inside logrotate's postrotate.
But when in a swarm mode, the way to restart the service is using "docker service update --force traefik". In this scenario, the service is restarted in every host participating in the swarm, but the logs are not rotated on every host. Am i missing something?

Comment: "assuming they're configured, on receipt of a USR1 signal" i can't figure out what this means.
So everytime logrotation rotates theres a new empty "access.log" file and logging is not visible anymore. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @RobertLachner I experienced this too. In my docker-compose.yml file, I was exporting the log files to the host system individually. When I stopped doing this and exported a directory instead (tell traefik to put the log files in here), the problem went away. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: it works now for me with the config i mentioned earlier.
Just added this config to "/etc/logrotate.d/traefik"
It can be tested with:

logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/traefik --debug

Answer (score 28):

If you are running **Traefik** in a **Docker** container then you can do something like this:

Check that logrotate is installed on the Docker host:

```
logrotate --version
```

Create file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`:

```
vi /etc/logrotate.d/traefik
```

Put the following script, do not forget to fill with the container name.

```
/var/log/traefik/*.log {
  size 10M
  rotate 5
  missingok
  notifempty
  postrotate
    docker kill --signal="USR1" <container-name>
  endscript
}
```

Run!

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf --debug 
logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Comment: This also works if Traefik is running outside Docker, in which case the line starting with `docker` should be adjusted. I configured Traefik as a Systemd service and set the command to `systemctl kill --signal="USR1" traefik`.

Comment: To me it didn't work with the quotes around the signal name, I had to remove them: `systemctl kill --signal=USR1 traefik`. I'm not sure why, but [it is used in this way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/#send-a-custom-signal--to-a-container) in the docker reference

Comment: Be aware of a bug in docker that will break the restart policy if you use `docker kill`: serverfault.com/a/1035576/1071187 Using `docker exec traefik kill -USR1 1` to send the signal from within the container is safer.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like there's no logrotation built-in so i enabled logrotation on the Host that `traefik_access.log` is mounted to.

In order for this to work when traefik is running in a docker container, you must volume mount the directory containing the log file (`/opt/traefik/logs`), not the log file itself (`/traefik_access.log`).

```
volumes:
  - /opt/traefik/logs:/logs
```

My logrotate-config for traefik 1.7.4 running in a container with volume mount to "/opt/traefik/logs":

```sh
/opt/traefik/logs/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 30
  missingok
  notifempty
  compress
  dateext
  dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
  create 0644 root root
  postrotate
  docker kill --signal="USR1" $(docker ps | grep traefik | awk '{print $1}')
  endscript
}
```

Comment: just mentioning to be mindful that other containers might also have a "traefik" component in their name - like error pages, etc. and the sub may return unexpected results for some

Comment: If you want to use the exact name, you could use `docker kill --signal="USR1" $(docker ps | grep '\btraefik\b' | awk '{print $1}')` - notice the `\b` before and after the container name.